# Install Rmagic / ImageMagic on win8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

My Rmagic gem stopped working. So i am attempting to re-install everything to get it working again.

The steps I have done so far.

**Downloaded different versions to test with**

```
ImageMagick-6.6.7-0-Q16-windows-dll.exe
ImageMagick-6.8.9-8-Q16-x64-dll.exe
ImageMagick-6.8.9-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe
```

**Installed in a path without any spaces**

```
"C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick"
```

**Installed with path and header settings ticked**

[image]

**Opened cmd with admin access and ran**

```
set CPATH=C:/RailsInstaller/ImageMagick/include
set LIBRARY_PATH=C:/RailsInstaller/ImageMagick/lib
```

**tried to install**

gem install rmagick

**I get the error message**

```
C:\Sites\website>gem install rmagick                           
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
   ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
   checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
   checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
   need configuration options.

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:431:in `try_do': The compiler failed to      generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
    You have to install development tools first.
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:562:in `try_cpp'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1041:in `block in have_header'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:892:in `block in checking_for'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:in `open'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:in `block in postpone'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:in `open'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:333:in `postpone'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:in `checking_for'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1040:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:186:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after re-installing and trying the following version worked for me

```
Ruby 1.9.3
ImageMagic 6.6.7-0 Q15
```

I also ran this command which installed rmagic successfully

```
gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-dir=C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick
```